# Is it possible to run IMPORT DATABASE command in PhpOrient?

Tags: php, orientdb

The connection is working correctly and I have the database selected.

```
$client->dbOpen('dbName');
```

All works until I try to run the command:

```
$client->command('IMPORT DATABASE /path/to/file/export.gz');
```

When I get this exception:

```
Message: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundException: Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.IMPORT DATABASE /path/to/file/export.gz -preserveClusterIDs=true DB name="dbname"
```

If the command `command` is not correct, then what can be use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/orientechnologies/PhpOrient/issues/15

Not possible yet (22 Jan 2017).